# Static reflection with Visual Studio 2008 targeting .net 2.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

Is there a trick to use [static reflection](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/26/introduction-to-static-reflection/) with Visual Studio 2008 targeting .net framework 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it isn't quite true that you need .NET 3.5 for this. What you need is the `Expression` classes; you can *write* these for 2.0 ([I've done it](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/04/re-implementing-expression-for-compact.html) for C# 3.0 targetting CF, which lacks `Expression`), but is isn't very easy, and I'd question the benefit.

If you value your sanity, I'd say stick with strings until you upgrade to 3.5. Sorry.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for: with LinqBridge (ExtensionAttribute) and your Expression source code I'm able to do things like this targeting .net 2.0:
firstNameTextBox.Bind(person, p => p.FirstName);

Thank you !

Comment: Wow... impressive ! It's the second time today that I'm proved wrong when I was pretty sure of my answer... but that's a good thing, I'm always glad to learn something new ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, because so called "static reflection" requires expression trees, which are only available in .NET 3.5+.

Note that [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), a library which makes some Linq features available to .NET 2.0 code, doesn't implement expression trees